# Run javascript in a dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a tool which generates some html+javascript code, it shows the code in one div and then shows a preview of what the code displays like in an iframe.

Here's a quick fiddle which shows this... http://jsfiddle.net/Zv4zU/

But the javascript within the iframe never runs even though if you inspect the iframe the javascript is definitely in there. How can I get the javascript to run by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPmw2/) for a solution!

Edit:
As Jonathan pointed out, I should also post the code here:

```
var html = "html code <script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK');<\/script>";
$("#myFrame").contents().find("body").html(html);
```

Comment: Please use fiddles as a supplement to your answer here. Please show your solution here, and link to a fiddle for demonstration purposes. This way, if jsfiddle were to even die, we'd still have the solution here.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be running the javascript on the parent, not on the iframe - example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BNG4n/ (the html of the page's 'test' div is shown, not the iframe's 'test' div, are there any fixes for this?

Comment: I'm going to ask above comment as new question as you did answer my initial question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit update your script to really start JS in the iframe:

```
var script = "alert('OK');document.body.innerHTML = 'hello!'";
myFrame.get(0).contentWindow.eval(script);
```

see [jsfeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv4zU/9/)